# how to print incorrect questions?

Tags: python

I am making a quiz in python and i want to know how i can display the incorrect questions at the end of the quiz. For example i have a 10 question quiz and i get 3 wrong, so i want to those questions to be displayed in the program and give me the option to re take them.

Here is my code:

```
correct=0
incorrect=0

def tryagain():
    while True:
       answer = input('Do you want to continue?:  Press Y for yes and N for no ')
       if answer.lower().startswith("y"):
          print()
       elif answer.lower().startswith("n"):
          exit()

print('****** Welceome to the Online Maths Test ********')
print()
print()
print()
print()
print()
print()
print()
import os
os.system("PAUSE")
import os
os.system('cls')
print('Question 1: 123 - 39 = ? \n 1. 64 \n 2. 44 \n 3. 74 \n 4. 84')
print()
answer=int(input())
if answer == 4:
        print ()
        print ()
        global correct
        correct=correct+1
elif answer != 4:
        print ()
        global incorrect
        incorrect=incorrect+1

import os
os.system('cls')
print('Question 2: 123+39 = ? \n \n 1. 162 \n 2. 166 \n 3. 62 \n 4. 66')
print()
answer=int(input())
if answer == 1:
        print ()
        print ()
        global correct
        correct=correct+1
elif answer != 1:
        print ()
        global incorrect
        incorrect=incorrect+1

import os
os.system('cls')
print('Question 3: 123*9 = ? \n 1. 1007 \n 2. 1107 \n 3. 1106 \n 4. 1116')
print()
answer=int(input())
if answer == 2:
        print ()
        print ()
        global correct
        correct=correct+1
elif answer != 2:
        print ()
        global incorrect
        incorrect=incorrect+1

import os
os.system('cls')
print('Question 4: 135 / 15 = ? \n 1. 8 \n 2. 8.5 \n 3. 9 \n 4. 9.5')
print()
answer=int(input())
if answer == 3:
        print ()
        print ()
        global correct
        correct=correct+1
elif answer != 3:
        print ()
        global incorrect
        incorrect=incorrect+1

import os
os.system('cls')
print('Question 5: 12 * (12 / 2) = ? \n 1. 144 \n 2. 6 \n 3. 72 \n 4. 36')
print()
answer=int(input())
if answer == 3:
        print ()
        print ()
        global correct
        correct=correct+1
elif answer != 3:
        print ()
        global incorrect
        incorrect=incorrect+1

import os
os.system('cls')
print('Question 6: 130 / 2 + 8 = ? \n 1. 13 \n 2. 14 \n 3. 61 \n 4. 84')
print()
answer=int(input())
if answer == 4:
        print ()
        print ()
        correct=correct+1
elif answer != 4:
        print ()
        global incorrect
        incorrect=incorrect+1

import os
os.system('cls')
print('Question 7: 10 + 12 + 13 * 6 / 2 = ? \n 1. 105 \n 2. 44 \n 3. 61 \n 4. 84')
print()
answer=int(input())
if answer == 3:
        print ()
        print ()
        global correct
        correct=correct+1
elif answer != 3:
        print ()
        global incorrect
        incorrect=incorrect+1

import os
os.system('cls')
print('Question 8: (10 + 12 + 13 * 6) / 2 = ? \n 1. 50 \n 2. 44 \n 3. 61 \n 4. 84')
print()
answer=int(input())
if answer == 1:
        print ()
        print ()
        global correct
        correct=correct+1
elif answer != 1:
        print ()
        global incorrect
        incorrect=incorrect+1

import os
os.system('cls')
print('Question 9: 8 (12 + 6 / 3 * 2) - 1 = ? \n 1. 127 \n 2. 109 \n 3. 95 \n 4. 135')
print()
answer=int(input())
if answer == 1:
        print ()
        print ()
        global correct
        correct=correct+1
elif answer != 1:
        print ()
        global incorrect
        incorrect=incorrect+1

import os
os.system('cls')
print('Question 10: 1 / 1 * 1 - 1 + 1 = ? \n 1. 1 \n 2. -1 \n 3. 0 \n 4. -2')
print()
answer=int(input())
if answer == 1:
        print ()
        print ()
        global correct
        correct=correct+1
elif answer != 1:
        global incorrect
        incorrect=incorrect+1
        print()
        print()
        print()
        print()
        import os
        os.system('cls')
        print('Your total score is: ',correct,' / 10')
        print('Your presentage is: ',correct*100/10,'%')
        print()
        print()
        print()
        print()
        tryagain()

tryagain()
```

Comment: You know, you don't have to `import os` every time you use it. I would also suggest you read about loops.

Comment: there's a benefit to posting a minimal example here. we don't need to see all ten questions to give you an answer. you could have posted a two or three question quiz.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would want to make sure to ask all of the questions in one place.  Then when it's time to make a change, such as record missed questions, you can make the changes in one place.

You can go further than my example by putting all of the questions into an array and looping through that array to ask the user questions.

```
import os

correct=0
incorrect=0
missed_questions=[]

def tryagain():
    while True:
       answer = input('Do you want to continue?:  Press Y for yes and N for no ')
       if answer.lower().startswith("y"):
          print()
       elif answer.lower().startswith("n"):
          exit()

def ask_question(question, correct_answer):
    os.system('cls')  # I'm not on Windows so this doesn't work for me
    print question
    print ''
    answer = int(input())
    if answer == correct_answer:
        print ''
        print ''
        global correct
        correct += 1
    else:
        global incorrect
        incorrect += 1
        global missed_questions
        missed_questions.append(question)


print('****** Welceome to the Online Maths Test ********')
print()
print()
print()
print()
print()
print()
print()
os.system("PAUSE") # I'm not on Windows so this doesn't work for me

## You could go further and put the data (all of the questions, correct answers, and
## a flag to indicate whether the user got it correct) into one array and loop
## through the array. In that same loop you can address how to make sure
## that the tryagain() works properly.
ask_question('Question 1: 123 - 39 = ? \n 1. 64 \n 2. 44 \n 3. 74 \n 4. 84', 4)
ask_question('Question 2: 123+39 = ? \n \n 1. 162 \n 2. 166 \n 3. 62 \n 4. 66', 1)
ask_question('Question 3: 123*9 = ? \n 1. 1007 \n 2. 1107 \n 3. 1106 \n 4. 1116', 2)
ask_question('Question 4: 135 / 15 = ? \n 1. 8 \n 2. 8.5 \n 3. 9 \n 4. 9.5', 3)
ask_question('Question 5: 12 * (12 / 2) = ? \n 1. 144 \n 2. 6 \n 3. 72 \n 4. 36', 3)
ask_question('Question 6: 130 / 2 + 8 = ? \n 1. 13 \n 2. 14 \n 3. 61 \n 4. 84', 4)
ask_question('Question 7: 10 + 12 + 13 * 6 / 2 = ? \n 1. 105 \n 2. 44 \n 3. 61 \n 4. 84', 3)
ask_question('Question 8: (10 + 12 + 13 * 6) / 2 = ? \n 1. 50 \n 2. 44 \n 3. 61 \n 4. 84', 1)
ask_question('Question 9: 8 (12 + 6 / 3 * 2) - 1 = ? \n 1. 127 \n 2. 109 \n 3. 95 \n 4. 135', 1)
ask_question('Question 10: 1 / 1 * 1 - 1 + 1 = ? \n 1. 1 \n 2. -1 \n 3. 0 \n 4. -2', 1)

print()
print()

os.system('cls')
print('Your total score is: ',correct,' / 10')
print('Your percentage is: ',correct*100/10,'%')
print()
print()

for q in missed_questions:
    print 'Missed question: ', q
    print ''

print()
print()
tryagain()
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, I realised you used list to count the incorrect questions. I didn't think list would work in this situation.

Comment: have you run this code? it seems to me that pressing y in try_again will keep you stuck in an infinite loop.

Comment: I ran the main part of the code.  Instead of fixing `tryagain()` I had added a comment about it in the example code because fixing it would have required creating a sort of "main" loop.

Comment: Yes my tryagain funcation is not correct. I made some changes to it: def tryagain():
    while True:
       answer = input('Do you want to try again?:  Press Y for yes and N for no ')
       if answer.lower().startswith("y"):
           os.system('cls')
           print('****** Welceome to the Online Maths Test ********')
           print()
           print()
           print()
           print()
           print()
           print()
           print()
           os.system("PAUSE")
           print(quiz())
       elif answer.lower().startswith("n"):
          exit()

Comment: I think that's really a separate question because you're trying to figure out how to drive the quiz inside of a loop and allow the user to control when to break out of the loop.